# rebuilding grails war file from ant

Tags: grails, deployment, ant

Grails war file are very big since they contains all the jars and plugins, this can be problematic when deploying on a virtual server since every small change I have to resend the whole war.

I found out that you can build the war file through ant directly on the server and send only the class files which are much smaller in size.

Can anyone tell me practically how this can be done?
Can I modify an existing war by changing some only some class files ?

Thanks, 
Dany

Comment: A war file is a zip file. you could unzip it, replace the files und zip it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hook into eventWarStart and customize the war.

See http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2009/01/21/excluding-files-from-a-war-with-grails-the-right-way/